# SVPWM Simulation

Tags: power-electronics, embedded, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am a student and I want to develop open loop SVPWM code with stm32. I created a Simulink model by doing research on the internet. But I have a few questions for you. The model I created is as follows:

[image]

First of all, because I used a 12V BLDC motor, I created 3 reference sine waves with 120 degrees phase difference and 12V amplitude. This part makes a voltage reading as if in a close loop.

[image]

Then I calculated theta and Vref values for these reference signals using Clarke transform. Next,

D2(Duty) = T2/Ts(0.00005) = a*sin(theta-(n-1)*pi/3)/sin(pi/3),

D1(Duty) = T1/Ts = a*sin(n*pi/3-theta)/sin(pi/3),

D0 = Ts(0.00005)-T1-T2 = 1-D1-D2;

For the formulas, I first calculated the value of a (Vref/(Vdc(12V)*2/3)) and then the sector number (n) according to the theta angle.

Then I calculated the switching times for each gate as in the model. Then, since these switching times are in the form of duty, my goal is to calculate the CCR value by multiplying these duty values with my ARR value (for example, ARR = 200) and modulate using it.

But as the output of this whole model, I get CCR values in excess of 200 in the scope below. Where am I going wrong? Can you please help me? Thank you very much in advance for your help and patience...

[image]

Comment: By the way, I'm using a carrier frequency of 20kHz and a reference frequency of 50Hz.

Comment: did you find your answer?? I have also some problems related to SVPWM.